# Sharepoint Workflow 2013/2013 - Create list item to document library creates corrupt document

Tags: workflow, document

I have recently upgraded a 2010 site to 2013 with spd workflow running on the 2010 platform. The "create list item" to a library does not seem to work. It adds a document but the file is corrupt and cannot be opened. Is this a bug in 2013?

Comment: Could you post your code for the custom workflow activity?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom workflow activity to create the document by passing the library amd the content type.